# Wait while jQuery.html() is fully loaded?

Tags: jquery

in jQuery I load some html into a div like this:

```
$("#test").html("Hello <img src='pic.jpg'>");
```

**Is there a way to know if the html is fully loaded?**
I mean i set the content, but the image needs a while to load.. I would like to wait until the whole html is loaded...

I could use $("img").load(... but it doesn't work for content loaded by $.html
Any other ideas?

Thanks

Comment: You could preload (in JS) the image and `onload` run your jQuery.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use a JS `Image` `onload` handler and add the markup there:

```
$("#btn").click(function(){
    var img = new Image();
    alert('onclick');
    img.onload = function(){
        $("#mycontent").html("<img class='futureImg' src='http://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/6/67/Rita_25_sept_2005_1640Z.jpg'>");
         alert('onload');
    }
    $("#mycontent").html("Image loading...");
    img.src = 'http://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/6/67/Rita_25_sept_2005_1640Z.jpg';
});
```

http://jsfiddle.net/FPu4P/6/

Note, the image will cache after opening the first time. It is a pretty large image, so it may take a moment or two to load.

**EDIT**

And, you could actually do the `.html()` addition and the JS cache at the same time (so far as I can tell):

```
$("#btn").click(function(){
    // Just so the image is not cached
    var r = Math.floor(Math.random()*1111111111);
    var url = 'http://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/6/67/Rita_25_sept_2005_1640Z.jpg?'+r;
    var img = new Image();
    alert('onclick');
    img.onload = function(){
         alert('onload');
    }
    $("#mycontent").html("<img class='futureImg' src='"+url+"'>");
    img.src = url;
});
```

http://jsfiddle.net/FPu4P/7/

Answer (score 5):

```
$("#test").html("Hello <img  class='futureImg' src='pic.jpg'>");

$(".futureImg").live('load',function () { alert('lalala');});
```

Comment: I think @Royi Namir's answer is better :)

Comment: jsFiddle is not pure develop enviroment. this statement also doesnt work and it should `$('body').load(function () { alert('lalala');});` http://jsfiddle.net/FPu4P/4/

Answer (score 2):

try:

```
$('#test').html("Hello <img src='pic.jpg'>").load(function(){
 // Ur task when it loaded.
});
```

Comment: I get `Uncaught TypeError: e.indexOf is not a function
    at w.fn.init.w.fn.load` when using this.

Answer (score 1):

why you don't use `.ready()` ?

Documentation: http://api.jquery.com/ready/

Answer (score 1):

The trick is to set the event listener before aiming the `<img>` at a file:

```
$("#test").html ("Hello <img />");
var newImg = $("#test > img");

newImg.load( function () {
    alert ('Success!');
} ).attr ('src', 'pic.jpg');
```

[**See it in action at jsFiddle.**](http://jsfiddle.net/FPu4P/9/)

Answer (score 0):

```
$("#test").load(function() {
    //your code after #test loaded
});
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$("#test").html('Hello <img src="pic.jpg">').find('img').load(...)
```

Comment: thanks, but it will fire up even if the img is not loaded. I mean maybe it is loaded into memory but it is not visible yet.

Answer (score 0):

Another solution not yet mentioned on this page would be to use jQuery's deferred objects like so:

```
var rq_html = $.get('.../somepage.html');
var rq_img = $.get('.../img/someimg.jpg');

$.when(rq_html, rq_img).then(function() 
{
  // both requests completed, append received html into DOM
  // and either rely on cache or insert img manually
}, function()
{
  // this function is failure handler in case one of the requests fails
  // the other request may still be pending at this point,
  // you might want to cancel it or handle the situation in another way...
});
```